# php input(php://input) stream empty on large data size

Tags: php, apache, cpanel, php-5.6

I am using HTML file API to upload file via ajax. I read the file using HTML API and submit the file as `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` as payload to server which is 912KB.

In php I am getting the file data using `file_get_contents('php://input')`. But it return empty.

This is working fine in localhost and but on the server it return empty. But when I submit small string like `Hello World` it returns the data.

Server Information:

```
PHP Version: 5.6.33
Build Date:  Feb 7 2018 02:51:40
OS: CENTOS 6.9
cpanel version: 68.0.29
post_max_size: 12M
upload_max_filesize: 12M
```

Local Server:

```
PHP Version: 5.6.25
OS: Windows
```

Comment: Could be a security setting on the server, try: `var_dump($_POST); var_dump($_GET)` and see if it outputs wanted data.

Comment: Already stated that `post_max_size` is `12M`

Comment: @Anuga var_dump($_POST); won't print anything as we are using the php input stream. We can only get it using file_get_contents('php://input').

Comment: Hi All,

I do not know what was the issue restarting the server did the trick. It is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what was the issue restarting the server did the trick. It is working fine now.